# E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'StrLen' SysUtils.pas(7863):

Tags: delphi-2010

My Code is below. Using Windows 10, Delphi 2010.
Error in `SysUtils.pas` file:

```
[DCC Error] OTFEFreeOTFE_U.pas(3199): E2251 Ambiguous overloaded call to 'StrLen'
  SysUtils.pas(7863): Related method: function StrLen(const PAnsiChar): Cardinal;
  SysUtils.pas(7892): Related method: function StrLen(const PWideChar): Cardinal;
```

**The Code piece is given below:**

```pascal
function StrLen(const Str: PAnsiChar): Cardinal;
asm
  {Check the first byte}
  cmp byte ptr [eax], 0
  je @ZeroLength
  {Get the negative of the string start in edx}
  mov edx, eax
  neg edx
  {Word align}
  add eax, 1
  and eax, -2
@ScanLoop:
  mov cx, [eax]
  add eax, 2
  test cl, ch
  jnz @ScanLoop
  test cl, cl
  jz @ReturnLess2
  test ch, ch
  jnz @ScanLoop
  lea eax, [eax + edx - 1]
  ret
@ReturnLess2:
  lea eax, [eax + edx - 2]
  ret
@ZeroLength:
  xor eax, eax
end;
```

Comment: Please show the source code of the error: OTFEFreeOTFE_U.pas line 3199. According to the message, this is SysUtiles.StrLen which is called and not yours. Use a fully qualified name instead.

Comment: This Line of code where error occurs:for i:=1 to deviceCount do
        begin
        devName := Copy(PChar(ptrBufferOffset), 1, StrLen(ptrBufferOffset));

        deviceNames.Add(devName);

        // Setup for the next one...
        ptrBufferOffset := Pointer(PChar(ptrBufferOffset) + FREEOTFE_MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH);
        end;

Comment: @MUHAMMADKASHIF what is `ptrBufferOffset` declared as? Because it is clearly not a `PAnsiChar` or a `PWideChar`. I'm guessing a raw `Pointer`, or maybe a `PByte`? You are using a `PChar` typecast to pick a particular `Copy()` overload, you need the same typecast to pick a `StrLen()` overload, too. In any case, you should use `SetString()` instead of `Copy()`, eg: `SetString(devName, PChar(ptrBufferOffset), StrLen(PChar(ptrBufferOffset)));` Or even simpler, just `devNames.Add(PChar(ptrBufferOffset));` since `ptrBufferOffset` must already be null-terminated in order for `StrLen()` to work at all

Comment: ptrBufferOffset is a pointer:ptrBufferOffset := Pointer(PChar(ptrBuffer) +
                         sizeof(ptrDIOCDeviceNameList^) -
                         FREEOTFE_MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH);
      for i:=1 to deviceCount do
        begin
        devName := Copy(PChar(ptrBufferOffset), 1, StrLen(ptrBufferOffset));

        deviceNames.Add(devName);

        // Setup for the next one...
        ptrBufferOffset := Pointer(PChar(ptrBufferOffset) + FREEOTFE_MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH);
        end;

Comment: And, did you try any of the things I mentioned in my earlier comment? And is the data that `ptrBufferOffset` is pointing at actually null-terminated to begin with? It makes a BIG difference in how you create strings from it. If the data is NOT null-terminated, then you can't use `StrLen()` at all.